# Есть ли аналог библиотеки chrono в C?

Tags: c++, c

Есть ли какая нибудь замена, либо аналогия временной C++ библиотеки chrono (в ходящей в пространство имен std) в C ??

Пытаюсь заменить C++ код на C код.

Пытаюсь работать с микросекундами.

Comment: [man gettimeofday](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/gettimeofday.2.html) (а также см. SEE ALSO в конце manpage)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Да @Alexey Nikolaev вы полностью правы.
НО хотел бы раскрыть вопрос. По сути за время в миллисекундах отвечает не библиотека, а сама операционная система. Что бы узнать микросекунды надо опросить её [АПИ](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/API) в Windows это [WinApi](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_API),  в Линуксе (Ubuntu) это [POSIX](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/POSIX).

Для работы с микросекундами в линусе стоит "работать" через функции : `gettimeofday` и `clock_gettime`

Для работы с микросекундами в windows стоит "работать" через функцию : `GetProcessTimes`

Вот пример работы с микросекундами в лунуксе (Ubuntu) :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <sys/time.h> // первый вариант gettimeofday
#include <time.h>   // второй вариант clock_gettime

int main()
{
    struct timeval stop, start;
    gettimeofday(&start, NULL);

    struct timespec start1, stop1;
    clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC_RAW, &start1); // можно такCLOCK_MONOTONIC_RAW и так можно CLOCK_REALTIME

    printf("Hello World!\n");
    int a = 1000;
    for (int i =0; i<a;i++)
        printf("%d \n",i);

    gettimeofday(&stop, NULL);
    printf("took %lu\n", stop.tv_usec - start.tv_usec);
     printf("------------------ \n");

     clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC_RAW, &stop1); // можно такCLOCK_MONOTONIC_RAW и так можно CLOCK_REALTIME
     uint64_t delta_us = (stop1.tv_sec - start1.tv_sec) * 1000000 + (stop1.tv_nsec - start1.tv_nsec) / 1000;
     printf("delta_us =  %d \n", delta_us);

    return 0;
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Увы в винде я пример предоставить не могу :( ибо в ней пока не работаю (даже если бы работал то попробовал реализовать через Qt).

Comment: Причем здесь GetProcessTimes? Скорее уж [GetSystemTimePreciseAsFileTime](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/sysinfoapi/nf-sysinfoapi-getsystemtimepreciseasfiletime)

Answer (score 0):

В Си библиотека работы со временем находится в [time.h](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time.h)

Comment: а работа с микросекундами  ??? Как я помню `time.h` это библиотека работы с днями недели и "бытовым" временем. Для программ работающих в режиме реального времени без микросекунд будет тяжеловато. Также лично по моему опыту все машины по сути работают в микросекундном диапазоне (возможно обывательское утверждение).

Comment: С микросекундами сложнее, но тоже возможно с помощью функции clock и дефайна CLOCKS_PER_SEC http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ctime/clock/

Comment: `$ man 7 time`  [В интернете](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/time.7.html)

Comment: Если я правильно понял, автор хотел узнать про стандартные средства работы со временем в Си. Но если требуется получить всю мощь на той или иной платформе, то для линукс - это POSIX (см. коммент выше), а для Windows - WinApi здесь - https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/SysInfo/time-functions

Comment: На многозадачной операционной системе получить стабильные выдержки времени и измерения с точностью меньше 10 миллисекунд уже сложно, вы же замахиваетесь на микросекунды.